# SELECT SUM - SQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a small database based on the Olympics for running a few sql queries from. I am trying to generate a table that displays each Country name and the total of Gold, Silver & Bronze medals won based on Athletes that are from these countries. Here is a screenshot of my Relational Model View:

[Relational Model View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZXZv.png)
[image]

Here is my query I am trying to run:

```
<h1>Olympics Database</h1>
<h3>Summary Information</h3>

    <h4>Number of Olympic Athletes from United Kingdom</h4>

<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', '#####', '#####') or die ('Could not connect:' . mysqli_error($conn));
    echo 'Successfully Connected. <br/>';

    mysqli_select_db($conn, '#####') or die('Database will not open');
    echo 'Database Connected. <br/> <br/>';

    $query2 = 'SELECT CountryAbbrev, (SELECT COUNT(CountryAbbrev) FROM athlete WHERE MedalID = 401 AND ath.CountryAbbrev = athlete.CountryAbbrev) AS Gold, (SELECT COUNT(CountryAbbrev) FROM athlete WHERE MedalID = 402 AND ath.CountryAbbrev = athlete.CountryAbbrev) AS Silver, (SELECT COUNT(CountryAbbrev) FROM athlete WHERE MedalID = 403 AND ath.CountryAbbrev = athlete.CountryAbbrev) AS Bronze FROM athlete AS ath';
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die ('Invalid Query');

    echo'<table><tr><th>Country Name</th><th>Gold</th><th>Silver</th><th>Bronze</th></tr>';
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
    echo'<tr><td>' .$row[0].'</td><td>' .$row[1].'</td><td>' .$row[2].'</td><td>' .$row[3].'</td></tr>';
    echo'</table>';

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

All I'm getting is invalid query. Going by my relation model view, could anyone help me figure out how I can display the total of gold, silver and bronze medals won by each country in a single table?

UPDATED: 
Here is a screenshot of the output:
[image]

Comment: Jou need to join medal and athlet LEFT JOIN Medal
ON  athlet.MedalID= Medal. MedalID

Comment: please provide sample data and expected result. Thanks

Comment: You'll also need a GROUP BY clause, as well as the tyoe of medal in the SELECT

Comment: `SUM(MedalID)` will sum ID values not count them.

Comment: On your `or die` you really want to be looking at `mysqli_error` to see what the actual problem is rather than guessing.

Comment: @Syscall I originally tried that, but it's showing up as Invalid Query. This is my first experience of running a sql query using php. I think I'm selecting from the wrong tables but I can't get my head around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original SQL query returns invalid query due to you are selecting undefined field in a table. i.e `athlete` table does not has a field named `MedalName`.

You may use the following SQL query, **by knowing the ids** for each medal type, I supposed that they are 1,2,3 for Gold, Silver and Bronze respectively.

```
SELECT CountryAbbrev,
 (SELECT COUNT(CountryAbbrev) FROM athlete WHERE MedalID = 1 AND ath.CountryAbbrev = athlete.CountryAbbrev) AS Gold, 
(SELECT COUNT(CountryAbbrev) FROM athlete WHERE MedalID = 2 AND ath.CountryAbbrev = athlete.CountryAbbrev) AS Silver, 
(SELECT COUNT(CountryAbbrev) FROM athlete WHERE MedalID = 3 AND ath.CountryAbbrev = athlete.CountryAbbrev) AS Bronze 
FROM athlete AS ath
```

### Update

Sorry, it should be `COUNT` instead of `SUM`. Checkout the difference between `SUM` and `COUNT` [from this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm beginning to see the sense in your approach. I have amended it slightly to match my MedalIDs. They are 401, 402, 403 for Gold, Silver and Bronze respectively as you suggested. Please see my answer again. I have updated with a screenshot of my result. It appears to only display 1 country and no medals

Comment: You did not make a valid loop through your result set. For now, just try the code in some tool such as phpMyAdmin and you will see the correct result, by this way, the SQL problem is solved, after that, search to know how to execute SQL queries using PHP and MySQL and render the obtained result.

Comment: thanks! I just ran the code in phpmyadmin and that works. I'm looking into a method now of creating a loop to return the values of all countries

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the "invalid query", you need a left join with `medal` table, change the `AND`s to `OR`s, and use a `group by` clause. Also, since you need the medal count, you need to replace `SUM` with `COUNT`. So you can do something like this:

```
SELECT CountryAbbrev as country, count(athlete.MedalID) 
FROM athlete 
  LEFT JOIN medal on medal.MedalID = athlete.MedalID
WHERE MedalName = "Gold" 
  OR MedalName = "Silver" 
  OR MedalName = "Bronze"
GROUP BY CountryAbbrev;
```

This query outputs the total medal count (# gold + # silver + # bronze) for each country:

```
+---------+------------------------+
| country | count(athlete.MedalID) |
+---------+------------------------+
| AU      |                      4 |
| US      |                      5 |
+---------+------------------------+
```

If you want to print out the count of gold, silver, and bronze individually in difference columns, then you can use following query:

```
SELECT CountryAbbrev as country, 
  sum(if(MedalName = "Gold", 1, 0)) as Gold, 
  sum(if(MedalName = "Silver", 1, 0)) as Silver, 
  sum(if(MedalName = "Bronze", 1, 0)) as Bronze 
FROM athlete 
  LEFT JOIN medal on medal.MedalID = athlete.MedalID 
WHERE MedalName = "Gold" 
  OR MedalName = "Silver" 
  OR MedalName = "Bronze" 
GROUP BY CountryAbbrev;
```

This query will output something like:

```
+---------+------+--------+--------+
| country | Gold | Silver | Bronze |
+---------+------+--------+--------+
| AU      |    1 |      2 |      1 |
| US      |    2 |      1 |      2 |
+---------+------+--------+--------+
```

And if you want to add a total column as well, try this query:

```
SELECT CountryAbbrev as country, 
  sum(if(MedalName = "Gold", 1, 0)) as Gold, 
  sum(if(MedalName = "Silver", 1, 0)) as Silver, 
  sum(if(MedalName = "Bronze", 1, 0)) as Bronze, 
  count(MedalName) as Total 
FROM athlete 
  LEFT JOIN medal on medal.MedalID = athlete.MedalID 
WHERE MedalName = "Gold" 
  OR MedalName = "Silver" 
  OR MedalName = "Bronze" 
GROUP BY CountryAbbrev;
```

This query will output:

```
+---------+------+--------+--------+-------+
| country | Gold | Silver | Bronze | Total |
+---------+------+--------+--------+-------+
| AU      |    1 |      2 |      1 |     4 |
| US      |    2 |      1 |      2 |     5 |
+---------+------+--------+--------+-------+
```

I've ran these queries on my machine and they work as expected.

Comment: still getting "Invalid Query"

Comment: Could you print out the actual error string using something like `die(mysqli_error($conn))`?

Comment: your code is working 100% for me in phpmyadmin but when I try to run is in php is doesn't seem to work! I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Gold' (T_STRING)

Comment: When you put it in php, escape the quotes using `\'` and `\"` or use a built-in php function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT c.CountryAbbrev, 
    (select count(a.MedalID) FROM athlete a WHERE c.CountryAbbrev=a.CountryAbbrev and a.MedalName = "Gold" ) as gold,
    (select count(a.MedalID) FROM athlete a WHERE c.CountryAbbrev=a.CountryAbbrev and a.MedalName = "Silver" ) as Silver,
    (select count(a.MedalID) FROM athlete a WHERE c.CountryAbbrev=a.CountryAbbrev and a.MedalName = "Bronze" ) as Bronze
from country as c
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. shouldn't you be selecting FROM athlete as a ?